# JOOQ keep setting schema to default PUBLIC

Tags: jooq

My gradle.build (using nu.studer.jooq plugin)

```
jooq {
    MyProject(sourceSets.main) {
        generator {
            database {
                name = 'org.jooq.meta.extensions.ddl.DDLDatabase'
                properties {
                    property {
                        key = 'scripts'
                        value = 'src/main/resources/database.sql'
                    }
                }
                inputSchema = ''
                outputSchema = 'something'
//                schemata {
//                    schema {
//                        inputSchema = ""    // I've tried this too
//                        outputSchema = 'something'
//                    }
//                }
                forcedTypes {
                    forcedType {
                        name = 'varchar'
                        expression = '.*'
                        types = 'JSONB?'
                    }
                    forcedType {
                        name = 'varchar'
                        expression = '.*'
                        types = 'INET'
                    }
                }
            }
            generate {
                relations = true
                springAnnotations = true
                deprecated = false
                fluentSetters = true
                // ...
            }
            target {
                packageName = 'com.springforum'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the build process, it can generate the schema just fine, but it keep using the `PUBLIC` schema for the output even though I've set outputSchema (I've tried using empty string and non-empty string)

---

Update: The problem only happen if `inputSchema` is empty, I tried with another sql script with schema and it works as intended

Comment: Why are you leaving the `inputSchema` empty? That's not allowed. But what do you want to achieve with that?

Comment: because my sql file doesn't use a schema (which is generated from pg_dump and it has no options to change this) , for example: CREATE TABLE table_name ();. I solved the problem by add a schema manually but I hope there is a way to allow me to do it

Comment: I see, my bad. I overlooked that you're using `DDLDatabase`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue that originates from the fact that behind the scenes `DDLDatabase` uses an H2 in-memory database to emulate running your SQL script, and then reverse engineers that H2 database. By default, in H2 (and a few other databases), everything goes in the `PUBLIC` schema. The issue is here: [#7650](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/7650)

#### jOOQ 3.11 workaround

Currently (as of jOOQ 3.11), I suggest you either specify the schema in your DDL script explicitly, or use `inputSchema = "PUBLIC"`, knowing the above.

#### jOOQ 3.12 solution

In jOOQ 3.12, this was fixed through [#7759](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/7759). It will be possible to specify the behaviour of unqualified schema objects:

```xml
<!-- The default schema for unqualified objects:
     - public: all unqualified objects are located in the PUBLIC (upper case) schema
     - none: all unqualified objects are located in the default schema (default) 

     This configuration can be overridden with the schema mapping feature -->
<property>
  <key>unqualifiedSchema</key>
  <value>none</value>
</property>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried again with `inputSchema = "PUBLIC"` and it fixed the problem. Haven't tried Jooq 3.12 solution yet.